# Cycle through multiple options of multiple select objects and select options based on SQL query result

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, electron

I am a newbie and have been working on a personal project in nodejs that's been giving me a bit of a headache. Hopefully I can get a bit of help.

Here is the situation: I have 5 select elements with the same classname that I cycle through. I then cycle through the options of each select element, and this works. Where I stumble into problems is that I want to get values from a SQL query(The connection is created). How do I cycle through the values in the table gotten from the SQL query and select multiple indices in each appropriate select element?

I hope this makes sense.

Here is what I have put together:

```
  //execute queries here
  var id = document.getElementById('idtext').value

  connection.query('SELECT * FROM doneon WHERE SampID LIKE ?', id, (err, rows, fields) => {
    if(err){
      return console.log('An error ocurred with the query', err)
    }
    var seleobje = document.getElementsByClassName('sele')
    for (var i=0; i<seleobje.length; i++){
      for (var j=0; j<seleobje.item(i).length; j++){
        for (var k=0; k<rows.length; k++){
          if (seleobje.item(i).options[j].value == rows[0].TestID){
            seleobje.item(i).options.selectedIndex = True
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I'm guessing I may have too many for loops, but I am unsure how else to do this. Thanks for all help you can provide.

Comment: Is your question about optimizing the looping (too many loops) or do you have an error when executing your code or does it not lead to the expected outcome?

Comment: By the way, `rows[0].TestID` will always reference to the TestID of the first row. Is this intended? Otherwise it should be `rows[k].TestID`

Comment: Sorry about that. I was fiddling with the code and forgot to rectify the rows[0] portion before copy-pasting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your question again, I think I have a solution for you.

You basically need to iterate through your rows in one loop and then get for each row-id all associated options (that have the same value).

You can do that easily using jQuery:

```
for (var k=0; k<rows.length; k++){
  var rowId = rows[k].TestID;
  $("[value='"+rowId+"']").each(function(element){
      this.selected = "selected";
  });
}
```

This code makes all `<option>`entries `selected` that match your row`s id. The full code would be:

```
//execute queries here
var id = document.getElementById('idtext').value

connection.query('SELECT * FROM doneon WHERE SampID LIKE ?', id, (err, rows, fields) => {
  if (err){
    return console.log('An error ocurred with the query', err)
  }

  for (var k=0; k<rows.length; k++){
    var rowId = rows[k].TestID;
    $("[value='"+rowId+"']").each(function(element){
      this.selected = "selected";
    });
  }
}
```

If have created a sample fiddle, that uses this code with some example data: https://jsfiddle.net/qgadhsLh/

Comment: Thanks man. I think there is an issue on my side though. I get this error: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [value=Activated Partial Thromboplastin Time]. Any ideas why.

Comment: I thought I would be able to skate through with javascript, but it looks like jquery is quite handy. I need to learn how it works. The much more condensed.

Comment: The options, in my case, are dynamically created with javascript by pulling information from aonther table, but not implemented manually in HTML. Could that be a factor causing this error?

Comment: The error comes from missing quotes in the `"[value='"+rowId+"']"` part. This causes values with whitespaces (as in your case) to throw errors. Pleace retry with the updated code.

Comment: Wow. That was perfect. Thanks again. Without your help, I'm sure I'd have probably spent the next five days figuring out I needed the quotes. Guess it's time for me to go learn jquery.